# Capturing first line from shell command output and continue processing rest

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to capture and "store away" (preferably in a variable) the first line of a command output and forward the remainder of the output back to stdin of the next command in a pipe. As an FYI, the purpose is to capture and store the cursor reference of a `redis-cli SCAN` invocation, while processing the data returned.

This is what I came up with:

```
command | { read first_line ; cat ; } | process_rest
echo $first_line
```

This seems to work as intended in zsh, but not in Bourne Shell ("/bin/sh") or bash. It appears that piping to the command grouping causes a subshell in sh/bash, "swallowing" the first_line variable.

What is the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Will I need to "pipe" the first line through a file or fifo instead of trying to set a variable? I also tried using a `while read line ; do` construct to filter out the first line and continue processing the rest, but it appears it has the same effect (any variable changes within the do/done block are not reflected in the outer scope).

Comment: @jhnc That is exactly the problem I am trying to solve. I need to not just remove the first line, but capture it for later use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the braces. In a POSIX shell, any command sequence involving pipes ( `cmd1 | cmd2` ) runs both in subshells.

To retain the value of `first_line` you must not run the `read` in a subshell.

With bash [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) you can do:

```
while
    IFS= read -r first_line
    consumer
do
    break
done < <( producer )
```

or

```
{ IFS= read -r first_line; consumer; } < <( producer )
```

Bash also has a [`lastpipe`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) option which is available when job control is disabled (typically scripts / non-interactive shells, or when disabled explicitly):

```
set +m
shopt -s lastpipe

producer | {
    IFS= read -r first_line
    consumer
}
```

---

[BashFAQ 024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) has more information and options.

Comment: This would set `$first_line` outside the while loop?

Comment: yes, it does, since `read` isn't performed in a subshell

Comment: Worth noting that lastpipe requires job control to be disabled; not a problem in scripts, but someone trying to smoketest the practices shown in this answer in an interactive shell might be surprised.

Comment: I have a follow up question. I like the second construct the best, but I can't figure out how to get the PID or return code of producer. I'd like to ensure that the process completed successfully down the line, but can't seem to figure out how. I added `"$?"` and `"$!"` to try to get the return code or pid in both the command block `{ ... }` and after the construct, but they always appear unset / not having the value I would expect.

Comment: I came up with a workaround for my specific use-case. The "value space" of `first_line` is not fully exhausted (i.e. I only expect producer to return positive integers) and I can encode the failure into the value captured in `first_line` (i.e. by echoing a negative integer from `producer`). Not ideal and not generally applicable, but will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
{ first_line=$(command | {
    IFS= read -r tmp
    printf '%s\n' "$tmp"
    process_rest >&3
  })
} 3>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a temporary file :

```
tempfile=$(mktemp)
command | { read -r first_line ; printf "%s\n" "$first_line" > "$tempfile"; cat ; } | process_rest
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way that works:

```bash
first_line=$(command | { read first_line ; echo $first_line ; process_rest })
echo $first_line
```

This will capture the first line while processing the remainder of the data. The main drawback of this approach is that I cannot easily redirect stdout of process_rest as part of the whole construct anymore. E.g.

```bash
get_data() {
  first_line=$(command | { read first_line ; echo $first_line ; process_rest }) 
  echo 2>&1 $first_line
}

get_data | do_something_else # derp
```

One possible solution to this might be to use a fifo:

```bash
get_data() {
  FIFO=$(mktemp -u)
  mkfifo $FIFO
  first_line=$(cat | { read first_line ; echo $first_line ; process_rest > $FIFO})
  echo 2>&1 first_line
  cat $FIFO
  rm $FIFO
}
get_data | do_something_else
```

Comment: I wonder if there's some exec FD redirection magic one can do to avoid having to create a FIFO for the last scenario, too.

Comment: As an aside -- avoid the backtick-based command substitution syntax. `$( )` has been standardized since the early 90s, nests better, and avoids having confusing side effects on the parsing process (backticks change how backslashes behave within them; nesting them gets very, _very_ messy)

Comment: (you might also think about preferring the standardized-since-the-90s `get_data() {` function declaration syntax, vs mixing it with 80s-era ksh `function get_data {` syntax in a way that's incompatible with _both_ the early-90s POSIX sh standard and 80s ksh. Yes, the "Advanced" Bash Scripting guide shows it that way, but continued insistence on showcasing bad-practice examples is much of why everyone else in the bash universe looks down on that so-called "reference").

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you. Edited the post. I was always under the impression that the `$()` syntax was bash specific and not portable. I guess that information is wildly outdated.

Comment: `mkfifo for-consumer; producer >for-consumer & { rm for-consumer; read first_line; consumer; } <for-consumer`

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can identify many common problems with shell code (including the use of legacy features such as backticks).  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 0):

If the output of `command` is textual and fairly small (anything up to 10K lines should be OK on any modern system) then you could store it all in memory and extract the pieces that you want.  This is one way to do it:

```
output=$(command)
readarray -t output_lines <<<"$output"
first_line=${output_lines[0]}
printf '%s\n' "${output_lines[@]:1}" | process_rest
```